# Issue with if in a stored procedure creation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

It's not a very complex problem I just have had some issues finding my same mistake somewhere else.

I need a stored procedure that will update the "state" of a table, instead of deleting it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_delete_user
    @id INTEGER
AS
    UPDATE USER
    IF (state = 0)
      SET state = 1
    ELSE 
      SET state = 0
    WHERE id = @id
GO
```

This however, throws an error...

I've also tried this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_delete_user
    @id INTEGER
AS
    IF state = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE user
        SET state = 0
        WHERE id = @id
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE user
        SET state = 1
        WHERE id = @id
    END
GO
```

But I get an error on the "state" saying invalid column name...

Comment: IF State = 1  - What is state?  It isn't defined.

Comment: It's a BIT value can be 1 or 0 not null(it's from the table itself), I'm trying to check if the current state is 1 and if it is then set it to 0 otherwise set it to 1

Comment: Then if it from the table you need to reference it from the table.  Like Jesus did below.  Until you are in a SELECT, UPDATE, etc statement you can't just reference the column.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Your current logic, working or not, makes no sense. If you "delete" a user, it seems you should set the state column to one specific value, not flip it. Otherwise, the name of your procedure does not match the logic it intends to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE flip_user_state
   @user_id int
AS
   UPDATE Users
   SET state = CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   WHERE user_id = @user_id
```